# How filter $lookup result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have a query that i use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and inside this query i need to passa a parameter to "filter" the results based in the field `scheduleStart` (i used a [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to pass the dates to my queries). I don't know where should i pass the parameters.

**My Query**

```
   User.aggregate([{
          $match: {
            storeKey: req.body.store,     
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              id: "$_id",
              name: "$name",
              cpf: "$cpf",      
              phone: "$phone",
              email: "$email",
              birthday: "$birthday",
              lastName: "$lastname"      
            },
            totalServices: {
              $sum: "$services"
            },    
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "schedules",
            "let": { "id": "$_id.phone" },
            "pipeline": [
               { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$customer.phone", "$$id"] }}},
               { "$project": { "scheduleStart": 1, "scheduleEnd": 1, "value": 1 }}
            ],
            "as": "user_detail"
          }  
        },  
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            name: 1,
            cpf: 1,      
            phone: 1,
            email: 1,
            birthday: 1,
            totalServices: 1,
            totalValue: { $sum : "$user_detail.value" },      
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            },
            user_detail: 1
          }
        },
```

The parameters that i want to pass in that query:

```
 start = '2018-12-13 00:00'
 period = '2017-01-13 00:00'
```

The actual result of my query:

```
6:
count: 1
totalServices: 0
totalValue: 73
user_detail: Array(2)
0: {_id: "5bb2832890c4f23d207b5d71", scheduleStart: "2018-10-02 08:20", scheduleEnd: "2018-10-02 08:40", value: 40}
1: {_id: "5bfd9c13e1193a4f30df05e4", scheduleStart: "2018-11-27 00:03", scheduleEnd: "2018-11-27 00:13", value: 33}

_id: {id: "5bfed8bd70de7a383855f09e", name: "Chris Santos G", phone: "11969109995", email: "csantosgrossi@gmail.com", birthday: "1992-03-06"}
```

How can i pass the parameter to filter by `scheduleStart` the results? I don't know if i need to pass inside the $lookup or after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter inside the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) pipeline inside `$match` stage using [**`$lte`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) and [**`$gte`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) query operators

```
{ "$lookup": {
  "from": "schedules",
  "let": { "id": "$_id.phone" },
  "pipeline": [
    { "$match": {
      "$expr": { "$eq": ["$customer.phone", "$$id"] },
      "scheduleStart": {
        "$lte": moment("2018-12-13 00:00").toDate(),
        "$gte": moment("2017-01-13 00:00").toDate()
      }
    }},
    { "$project": { "scheduleStart": 1, "scheduleEnd": 1, "value": 1 }}
  ],
  "as": "user_detail"
}}
```

Comment: I'm using the line of `ScheduleStart` to test like this `scheduleStart: { '$gte': '2017-12-14 23:59', '$lte': '2018-12-14 00:00' }` and won't work

Comment: Because type of the field matters here. You have taken it as `date` in schema and here you are passing here as `string`. That's why we used `moment` here

Comment: but in my schema the field is a string too

Comment: @Matheus Sorry for the late reply. But if is a string in your database and you pass it as a string here then it should work. You can see it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/90wb3fKOhKv)

Comment: I know, your answer is right, but here doesn't work yet.

Comment: @Matheus If you show some sample collections where it doesn't work then I think I can help you.

Comment: What do you need? The result shows all the registers and don't filter by dates